# how to check an items stored in a shared preference if it is equal to a new entry to this shared preference

Tags: android

I have 2 problems with shared preference .. the first one each time when I try to store a new data to a shared preferences the old one is overwritten !!

also I've used method "Contains(String key)" to compare the new entry with the old ones if they equal !! , BUT I think this is not correct ! 
what is the best way to compare the new entry with the old ones in shared preferences if if it is equal with one of the old entries ??

this is my code for registration :

```
   package com.example.task_8;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Ac_3 extends Activity {

    Button save;
    EditText userName,password,userId;
    String name,pass,Id;
    Intent i;
     SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        setContentView(R.layout.ac_3);

        save= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        userId=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("myshared", 0);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

          i = getIntent();




            TextWatcher listener = new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    name= userName.getText().toString();
                    pass= password.getText().toString();
                    Id=userId.getText().toString();

                    } 


            };

            password.addTextChangedListener(listener);
            userName.addTextChangedListener(listener);



            save.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    if(!(Id.equals(sp.contains(Id))))
                            {


                    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
                    spe.putString("userName",name);
                    spe.commit();
                    spe.putString("password",pass);
                    spe.commit();
                    spe.putString("userId",Id);
                    spe.commit();

                            }

                    else 

                    {

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
                        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Ac_3.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("error msg");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("The two passwords does not match");
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }


                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }




            });



}

}
```

and in the main activity I want to check existence of this entry if I want to make login :

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(!name.equals(null) && !pass.equals(null))
                    {

                        if(sp.contains(Id)&&sp.contains(name)&&sp.contains(pass))

                        {

                            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ac_2.class);
                            i.putExtra("userName", name);
                            i.putExtra("password", pass);
                            i.putExtra("userId", Id);
                            startActivity(i);


                        }

                        else {
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("error msg");
                            //alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",this);
                            //alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
                            alertDialog.setMessage("You should register before");
                            alertDialog.show();
                            /*alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                          if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                                                      //do what ever you want on OK click
                                                    }  
                                        }
                                    }); */


                        }



                    }

                }


            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can get It firstly what u have already stored in SharedPreference.

```
      String oldUser=spe.gettString("userName",name);

      String oldpass= spe.getString("password",pass);

       String oldId= spe.getString("userId",Id);
```

Now, comapre them with new values as per your requirement:

e.g:

```
if(Id.equalsIgnoreCase(oldId))
{
//it contains
}
else
{}
```